# Scan for ASCII values of string characters

Tags: c++

I want to check if a string contains any characters other than 0-9 or A-Z and if it does, stop the program. This is what I did:

```
string number_in;

for (int i = 0; number_in[i] == '\0'; i++)
{
    if ( (number_in[i] < 48) || ( (number_in[i] > 57) && (number_in[i] < 65) ) || (number_in[i] > 90) )
    {
        cout << "\nInput number contains incorrect characters!\n";
        getchar;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But whichever string I would enter, it always skips the for loop. Why is that so?

Comment: Change your numbers:  `(number_in[i] < '0').  Use character constants instead.  Trust the compiler to convert them into the correct ASCII numeric value.

Comment: You need to change you input data to all `\0', so the *loop continues*, because you told the compiler to make the loop *continue while* number[i] equals '\0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`number_in[i] == '\0'` should be `number_in[i] != '\0'`. The for loop to runs while the condition is true.

Answer (score 3):

`number_in[i] == '\0'` seems to be incorrect. It is the condition for the loop to *continue* to run.

However, there is an easier solution using [`std::isalnum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum) and [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of):

```
bool stopProgramm = !std::all_of( std::begin(str), std::end(str),
                                  [] (unsigned char c) 
                                  { return std::isdigit(c) || std::isupper(c); } );
```

Comment: That's a lot more readable than the otherwise mysterious ASCII codes. It's not immediately obvious what 48 is, and it's not obvious if that's wrong.

Comment: The OP specifically said A-Z, i.e., upper-case only.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas Well, there is an easy fix. Not quite as sexy though.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
#include <cctype>

// ...

  char const c = number_in[i];
  if ( !(isascii(c) && (isdigit(c) || isupper(c))) ) {
    // ...
  }
```

Strictly speaking, `isascii(c)` isn't needed, but, if you want to be cross-platform, the other `is*()` functions break on Windows if `c` isn't ASCII.